# How can I make Ctrl + Right Arrow work in SecureCRT?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, securecrt

Why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> work in SecureCRT? 
How can I make it working?

Answer (score 4):

On the remote system, first put in ~/.inputrc:

```
"\777": backward-word
"\002": forward-word
```

Then click SecureCRT menu "Option/Session options",  go to Terminal/Emulation/Mapped keys in the left, click "map a key..." button in the right, press "ctrl-left arrow", in "Map selected key" dialog, select "Send string" in left and input "\777" in the right "Send string" box. Do it again for "Ctrl-right arrow", except that you input "\002".

You can choose other strings to be sent than "\777" and "\002". If so, be sure to modify both in .inputrc and "send strings".

Now you can use 'ctrl-arrows' to skip words in console.

EDIT: '\001' will disable 'ctrl-A' (move to the beginning of the line).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this very same problem recently (in SecureCRT 7) and learned two important things:

1) Switching your **Terminal** -> **Emulation** to **Xterm** fixes this.

2) Before I discovered Xterm, I wrote a short tutorial on how to map the key combination to work in Linux:

Here's the steps:

1) Go to **Options** -> **Global Options**

2) Click **Default Session** -> **Edit Default Settings**

3) Click **Terminal** -> **Emulation** -> **Mapped Keys** -> **Map a Key**

4) When prompted, press **Ctrl + Left Arrow** then type:
  **\033\142** 
...and click **OK**

5) Do the same for **Ctrl + Right Arrow** then type: 
  **\033\146** 
...and click **OK**

6) Click **OK** to dismiss.  Dismiss the **Session Options** window and then click **Change ALL sessions** (no undo)

Tip: You'll have to close and re-open sessions that are currently connected before it works for them.

Hopefully this helps someone.  :-)

Comment: This is the best answer for SecureCRT installed in Microsoft Windows OS as there is no such `~/.inputrc` file in Windows. Thanks @Jeremy

Comment: @Jeremy This helped me! Works on my Mac. I changed it to Alt+Arrow instead. Thank you.

Comment: @Sabrina To be clear, the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/414357/)'s reference to `~/.inputrc` was for the remote system, not the Windows system running SecureCRT.